# Built-in VPN errors 20027 and 20063

Tags: windows-10, drivers, vpn

I am experiencing a problem with Windows VPN on my Lenovo Ideapad, running Windows 10 1909. The problem makes a lot of network-related settings pages work very slowly. For example, it takes a long time for the list of WiFi networks to load when I click on the icon in the taskbar (and it leaves out the VPN networks). The network pages in the Settings app also work very slowly. Finally, when I try to connect to a VPN (after getting to the page), it gets stuck saying "Connecting". The VPN I use is L2TP/IPSec with PSK, using the built-in VPN provider.

I found the following errors in Event Viewer (System):

1. RasMan - 20027 - Remote Access Connection Manager failed to start because NDISWAN could not be opened.
2. RasMan - 20063 - Remote Access Connection Manager failed to start because the Protocol engine [C:\WINDOWS\system32\vpnike.dll] failed to initialize. The system cannot find the device specified.
3. Service Control Manager - 7023 - The Remote Access Connection Manager service terminated with the following error:
   The system cannot find the device specified.

These errors occur in this order whenever I try to use those network settings pages or connect to a VPN.

My problem is just about identical to the one discussed on [this SpiceWorks thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2278447-unable-to-connect-to-vpn). However, I have tried everything there and it did not work. I'm honestly not sure how removing vpnike.dll fixed the problem for the person on SpiceWorks, considering that there wouldn't be anything to handle IKE...

Things I have tried:

- `sfc /scannow`
- Registering vpnike.dll using `regsvr32`
- `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` and rebooting
- `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` (No component store corruption detected)
- Comparing vpnike.dll and ndiswan.sys to files on other computers - I took a SHA256 hash and it matched other Windows 10 1909 computers.
- Renaming vpnike.dll
- Renaming vpnike.dll and then running `sfc /scannow` - This allows the settings pages to work, but when I try to connect to a VPN, it says "A device of that type does not exist." No error in the event log.
- Restarting, renaming vpnike.dll, running `sfc /scannow`, and renaming vpnike.dll again... (Still says "A device type was specified that does not exist.")
- Renaming ndiswan.sys
- Renaming ndiswan.sys and running `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Please make sure you have patched your OS with fully windows updates. If you remove VPN connection , will you still encounter network-related settings slowly issue?

Comment: @Candy Windows is fully updated (including Tuesday's updates). Removing VPN connections has no effect - network settings pages still load slowly, showing the same three errors in the event log. Network Status is the only page that opens quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same situation. All the mentioned changes didn't help. As a desperate approach, I tried to upgrade to Windows 11. This also failed, because of the missing TPM 2.0 module. I opened the device manager and found the "Trusted Platform Module 2.0" with a yellow warning sign. As a side effect the part "Network adapter" changed its state from 3 entries to 11 entries back and forth (adding and removing 8 WAN Miniport entries automatically every 30 seconds or so).

I was able to catch one of this appearing and disappearing WAN Miniports and could right click it. An error about "missing registry entry or access right" was shown.

Under properties, Drivers I tried to update the driver with an existing one "from my computer". I just selected the one offered automatically. I didn't select something special or some own driver from a special location.

This seems to fix not only the selected WAN Miniport, also the 7 other entries stopped disappearing and appeared permanently.

A short attempt to start one of my VPN connections showed eventually the normal behaviour and immediately connected to the target.

Unfortunately, I never found the cause for this problem.